# How can we prevent an azure function from processing already processed blob?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-functions

I have an azure function, which is binded to blob storage. Once the blob is successfully processed I rename the file with a suffix '-Processed'.

But my azure function again picks up the same blob for processing. I tried putting {name}.csv filter in the BlobTrigger binding but that didn't help as the file will still be a csv even after the rename.

I know I can filter blobs to have a particular string in file name, for eg "original-{name}" will filter files starting with original.
But Is there a way in azure functions using which I can filter the blob names to not include a particular string, in my case '-Processed'?

Comment: Instead of renaming, just move it over (blob output binding) to an _output_ container.

Answer (score 4):

1. Just use two different paths for processed and not processed blobs.
2. Put your new blobs with prefix ("notprocessed-" for example), when renaming remove prefix. Set `"path": "input/notprocessed-{name}"`

Comment: I implemented with a similar approach. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, blob service only **supports filtering by blob prefix and not by suffix**. Your only option would be to list blobs  and then do client side filtering.

Also, the list blobs operation has an additional `delimiter` parameter that enables the caller to traverse the blob namespace by using a user-configured delimiter.

You could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/enumerating-blob-resources) for more details.