# Blob trigger binding should exclude when URL contains Thumbnails

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-functions

I would like to unbind blob trigger if path contains thumbnails. 
I tried with **BlobTrigger("ProfilePhoto/`*~thumbnails`*/{name}"** this. it's not working. Could you please help me here.

Comment: Where did you get that expression to exclude part of the path? I don't see anything like that in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-triggers-bindings#binding-expressions---trigger-file-name).

Comment: It was tried with my self. may I get any possible solution here ?

Comment: The solution would be to let it trigger on any blob path and then check the path in your function code. If the path has `thumbnails` then exit.

Comment: Unnecessarily Trigger will hit and it will impact to cost also. it will be a workaround

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can we prevent an azure function from processing already processed blob?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50434530/how-can-we-prevent-an-azure-function-from-processing-already-processed-blob)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't apply arbitrary filters with search patterns. You can only filter by prefix of the blob name, so you should organize blobs accordingly.

Either use separate containers for thumbnails and not-thumbnails, or use `thumbnail-` prefix for thumbnail blobs.

Comment: We created one more container for thumbnail images. but we are generating saskey with grammatically for read images. now we need to create saskey for two containers need to maintain same from client side also.